# I am getting error when placing below code in wordpress theme function file to change canonical URL in mass using Yoast SEO plugin

Tags: javascript, php

Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 35 of file wp-content/themes/Newspaper/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING)

==================================================

and I am using this code for mass changes in canonical URLs:

---

```
// Batch Change Canonical URLs
function change_canonical($url) {
    global $post;

    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
         return 'https://templeshistory.in/' . $post->post_name;
    } else {
         return $url;
    }
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'change_canonical' );
```

---

If this code is wrong can you please provide me the right code for these changes in canonical URLs of all post pages.

Comment: There's no syntax issues here. Which line is line 35?

Comment: this is in line no 35:   return 'https://templeshistory.in/' . $post->post_name;

Comment: have you found the solution to it?

Comment: The issue isn't visible here. Maybe there's a hidden character somewhere?

Comment: but before placing this code everything is ok and if I remove this again then don't come to an error.